# MySQL localhost / 127.0.0.1 problem

Tags: php, mysql, sockets, localhost

I have a local web server running on my macbook and I've come across a strange problem.  I can access MySQL just fine using a program like Sequel Pro, password works and life is great.

Within PHP, if I have the db server as 127.0.0.1, everything works as well.

However, if I change the db server to localhost, I get access denied for 'root'@'localhost' errors.  I've made sure the MySQL socket is setup correctly, but still cannot use localhost.

Any insight would be awesome.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Besides Michael's words,

there's another link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connecting.html, it says:

> On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name localhost specially, in a
>   way that is likely different from what you expect compared to other
>   network-based programs. For connections to localhost, MySQL programs
>   attempt to connect to the local server by using a Unix socket file.
>   This occurs even if a --port or -P option is given to specify a port
>   number.

it's not a typical tcp/ip connection. if u have local port forwarding from 127.0.0.1:3306 to 192.168.1.2:3306, "mysql -h localhost" will try to connect to local unix socket file.

it's not specific to your question(since u're running php), but hope it helps anyway.

Answer (score 4):

From [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/access-denied.html).

Set the initial password for the root user on localhost.

SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost=PASSWORD('new_password');
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Comment: This was the less voted, but the real answer to his question :)

Answer (score 1):

In your my.cnf file, either change your **bind-address** to localhost or remove the **bind-address** setting entirely (which will make mysql listen on all IP's).

The my.cnf file is usually in /etc or /etc/mysql.

Comment: Are there any major security concerns to removing the bind-address setting altogether?

Comment: If your machine has multiple IP addresses, then you would be exposing your server to all of those IPs.  If you're talking about a single IP machine I wouldn't expect it to be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is what fixed it for me. PHP.INI defaults to a different location than MySQL for the default socket. To fix, just run these two commands to add an alias (no restart needed):

```
mkdir /var/mysql
ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

[Source](https://serverfault.com/a/228702/196015)