# Python connecting to mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I installed Python 2.7 to try to connect to MySQL online. Basically, MySQL and phpMyAdmin is on a server and I can access it via `localhost:8888/phpmyadmin` via putty on my windows desktop. I cant seem to connect to it even with the putty on. Any idea? I face the same issue with Python 3.3 using CyMySQL.

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1", # your host, usually 127.0.0.1
                     user="megamonster", # your username
                     passwd="", # your password
                     db="extractor") # name of the data base

# you must create a Cursor object. It will let
#  you execute all the query you need
cur = db.cursor() 

# Use all the SQL you like
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM abc")

# print all the first cell of all the rows
for row in cur.fetchall() :
    print row[0]
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\testSQL.py", line 6, in <module>
    db="extractor") # name of the data base
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061)")
```

Update

i added port(3306) and got this.
OperationalError: (2013, "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 0")

Currently looking at
[MySQL error: 2013, "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578147/mysql-error-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-at-reading-initial-communic)

Hmm cant work still...

Comment: can you connect with "mysql -umegamonster extractor" on the machines command line?

Comment: Try `localhost` instead of the ip address?

Comment: @kevinsa5 tried that already. I'm considering something like restful or some api stuff hmm what do you suggest?

Comment: @joeButler i have no issues in connecting to mysql from putty / browser(phpmyadmin)

Comment: I think you forgot the `port` variable.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac yea i just added it , new error and found a article on it , do you agree with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578147/mysql-error-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-at-reading-initial-communic

Comment: @RainbowHat Why not just use sqlite? :P

Comment: @GamesBrainiac I'm using python 2.7 , Windows , trying to connect to a online phpmyadmin/mysql. I'm tunneled via putty. Hmm because i use mysql for my website :)

Comment: How often do you ask this today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used sqlplus it worked

```
sqlplus User_name/password@Host_ip:Port/Service_Name@$SQLFILENAME
```

Just specify the `SQLFILENAME` if you want to utilize a file. Otherwise, you can ignore this parameter and can directly run sql statements

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a number of things, but as far as MySQL is concerned, permissions are set independently for `localhost` and for `127.0.0.1`. Make sure you can connect with the exact host and credentials. [Possibly related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5239412/1681480)

For example, check this when connected with your PUTTY connection.

```
mysql> use mysql;
Database changed

mysql> SELECT host,user,select_priv FROM user;

+-------------------------+------+-------------+
| host                    | user | select_priv |
+-------------------------+------+-------------+
| localhost               | root | Y           |
| 127.0.0.1               | root | Y           |
+-------------------------+------+-------------+
```

Also check who you are connected as (on PUTTY) and use that same info in the script:

```
mysql> SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();

+----------------+----------------+
| USER()         | CURRENT_USER() |
+----------------+----------------+
| root@localhost | root@localhost |
+----------------+----------------+
```

Comment: I checked, Yes , Localhost and 127.0.0.1 is same as above. for current_user , same as your result as above.

Comment: So you can ssh to the machine and then connect at the command line as `mysql -u root`? I don't understand the phpmyadmin "via Putty" reference... Nevermind -- I just saw the edit to your post that you have a new error!

Comment: yes. Thanks for helping me debug this , been saerching for hours. I appreciate your help >.< Still trying hard :x Hmmm

Comment: I just dont understand why if i can talk to mysql via putty & browser http://localhost:8888/phpmyadmin why i cant do it on python :\

Comment: I'm so desperate , if this cant work , would u suggest something else? eg restful / api stuff ? i'm new to those anyway :\

Comment: In your script, try port 3306 instead of 8888? (Assuming you were using 8888 from your phpmyadmin statement). I think this question is basically finished because you have solved the problem originally asked, so we can't go off and start to debug another error in the comments.