# Docker not running on local host for windows machine

Tags: docker

I am new to Docker and I am trying to test my application on local host(windows machine). In CLI, after running docker run command, it shows that it is up and running on local host. However, when I try to open the URL in browser, page shows message that "This site can’t be reached". I am using docker desktop and base image of alpine. I may be missing something on this issue. Is it something related to issue on windows ? (One more thing, When I use docker ps --a command, I can see container's name but port numbers are missing. Port numbers are visible on docker desktop).

Stuck with this since many days. Please help !!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Please take some time to review the guidelines for asking a question here.  Your question is not related to programming and probably belongs on a different stack.

Answer (score -1):

You need to bind your program to host `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`. Unfortunately no further help can be provided unless you specify what docker container/application you're trying to use.

[Localhost vs 0.0.0.0 with Docker on Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47025647/localhost-vs-0-0-0-0-with-docker-on-mac-os)