# nestjs grpc client cannot resolve dns to grpc service inside docker container

Tags: typescript, docker, nestjs, grpc, grpc-node

I have a grpc service and a simple http server serving as a grpc client. They work fine when running locally. However, once put inside separate docker containers, they cannot establish a connection. The grpc service runs and exposes port :5001.

Registering the grpc service in nestjs grpc client app

```
  ClientsModule.register([
      {
        name: "TOKEN_NAME",
        transport: Transport.GRPC,
        options: {
           ...GRPC_OPTIONS,
           url: process.env.GRPC_SERVICE_URL
        },
      },
    ]),
```

I've tried using container name as URL:

```yaml
version: '3.9'
services:
  grpc-service:
    restart: always
    build: ./grpc-service
    container_name: grpc-service
  grpc-client:
    restart: always
    build: ./backend
    container_name: grpc-client
#    links:
#      - "grpc-service:service"
    depends_on:
      - grpc-service
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - GRPC_SERVICE_URL=http://grpc-service:5001
#     - GRPC_SERVICE_URL=http://service:5001
```

and also tried creating a network and assigning IP addresses:

```yaml
version: '3.9'
networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 179.20.0.0/24

services:
  grpc-service:
    restart: always
    build: ./grpc-service
    container_name: grpc-service
    networks:
      mynetwork:
        ipv4_address: 179.20.0.5
  grpc-client:
    restart: always
    build: ./backend
    container_name: grpc-client
    networks:
      mynetwork:
        ipv4_address: 179.20.0.6

    depends_on:
      - grpc-service
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - GRPC_SERVICE_URL=179.20.0.5:5001
```

### Errors:

#### Using http://grpc-service:5001

```bash
grpc-client       | [Nest] 1  - 09/20/2022, 12:20:14 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] 14 UNAVAILABLE: Name resolution failed for target dns:http://grpc-service:5001
grpc-client       | Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Name resolution failed for target dns:http://grpc-service:5001
grpc-client       |     at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:19)
grpc-client       |     at Object.onReceiveStatus (/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:190:52)
grpc-client       |     at Object.onReceiveStatus (/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:365:141)
grpc-client       |     at Object.onReceiveStatus (/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:328:181)
grpc-client       |     at /node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:188:78
grpc-client       |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
grpc-client       | for call at
grpc-client       |     at ServiceClientImpl.makeUnaryRequest (/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:160:30)
grpc-client       |     at ServiceClientImpl.<anonymous> (/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/make-client.js:105:19)
grpc-client       |     at Observable._subscribe (/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/client/client-grpc.js:177:35)
grpc-client       |     at Observable._trySubscribe (/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Observable.js:41:25)
grpc-client       |     at /node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Observable.js:35:31
grpc-client       |     at Object.errorContext (/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/util/errorContext.js:22:9)
grpc-client       |     at Observable.subscribe (/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Observable.js:26:24)
grpc-client       |     at /node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/lastValueFrom.js:10:16
grpc-client       |     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
grpc-client       |     at lastValueFrom (/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/lastValueFrom.js:7:12)
```

#### Using 179.20.0.5:5001

```bash
grpc-client       | [Nest] 1  - 09/20/2022, 12:22:14 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] 14 UNAVAILABLE: No connection established
grpc-client       | Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: No connection established
grpc-client       |     at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:19)
grpc-client       |     at Object.onReceiveStatus (/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:190:52)
grpc-client       |     at Object.onReceiveStatus (/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:365:141)
grpc-client       |     at Object.onReceiveStatus (/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:328:181)
grpc-client       |     at /node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:188:78
grpc-client       |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
grpc-client       | for call at
grpc-client       |     at ServiceClientImpl.makeUnaryRequest (/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:160:30)
grpc-client       |     at ServiceClientImpl.<anonymous> (/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/make-client.js:105:19)
grpc-client       |     at Observable._subscribe (/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/client/client-grpc.js:177:35)
grpc-client       |     at Observable._trySubscribe (/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Observable.js:41:25)
grpc-client       |     at /node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Observable.js:35:31
grpc-client       |     at Object.errorContext (/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/util/errorContext.js:22:9)
grpc-client       |     at Observable.subscribe (/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Observable.js:26:24)
grpc-client       |     at /node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/lastValueFrom.js:10:16
grpc-client       |     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
grpc-client       |     at lastValueFrom (/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/lastValueFrom.js:7:12)
```

**EDIT**

I have also tried running the grpc service inside docker with port mapping `5001:5001` with http client ran locally attempting to connect with the grpc service on `localhost:5001`. In this case I get `connection dropped error`

```
  [Nest] 93680  - 09/24/2022, 2:52:50 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connection dropped
Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connection dropped
         at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/Users/grpc-docker/backend/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/call.ts:81:17)
         at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/grpc-docker/backend/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client.ts:352:36)
         at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/grpc-docker/backend/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client-interceptors.ts:462:34)
         at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/grpc-docker/backend/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client-interceptors.ts:424:48)
         at /Users/grpc-docker/backend/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/call-stream.ts:330:24
         at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
  for call at
  at ServiceClientImpl.makeUnaryRequest (/Users/grpc-docker/backend/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client.ts:324:26)
  at ServiceClientImpl.<anonymous> (/Users/grpc-docker/backend/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/make-client.ts:189:15)
  at Observable._subscribe (/Users/grpc-docker/backend/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/client/client-grpc.js:177:35)
  at Observable._trySubscribe (/Users/grpc-docker/backend/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Observable.ts:245:19)
  at /Users/grpc-docker/backend/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Observable.ts:235:18
  at Object.errorContext (/Users/grpc-docker/backend/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/util/errorContext.ts:29:5)
  at Observable.subscribe (/Users/grpc-docker/backend/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Observable.ts:221:5)
  at /Users/grpc-docker/backend/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/lastValueFrom.ts:59:12
  at new Promise (<anonymous>)
  at lastValueFrom (/Users/grpc-docker/backend/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/lastValueFrom.ts:56:10)
```

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting?

Comment: @OneCricketeer updated the post to include errors. Basically, either Connection is not established or DNS can't be resolved

Comment: Nothing in your compose file is called `comments-service`, so the error is "correct"

Comment: @OneCricketeer it is, names where changed for stack overflow. Didn't do that for errors.

Comment: Got it. So, have you tried removing http protocol from the first method since you're not using it on the second?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Tried both removing http protocol from first approach (using container name) and adding http protocol to second approach (IP address). Same errors occur but the other way round so first one has `no connection established` and the other one has `name resolution failed`. :/

Comment: @OneCricketeer even better. I exec'ed into the http client container and pinged the IP address and it worked - 0% packet loss. So it's not the problem with networking. I then tried running the grpc service in docker with port mapping `5001:5001` but ran the http client locally. I got a connection dropped error 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the issue was with how the grpc service was being started.

Nestjs's `createMicroservice` method accepts [grpc options](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/grpc#options), one of which is a url.
Mine was set to `localhost:5001`, however, apparently that does not make it accessible from outside the container. After changing it to `0.0.0.0:5001` there was no more issues establishing a connection. After figuring this out I've found a [stack exchange thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47025647/localhost-vs-0-0-0-0-with-docker-on-mac-os) explaining it in more detail.